# Django: All Form Error Messages as a single string

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to access a form error message as text within a view and use it as a single string.

```
error_string = ' '.join(form.errors['email'].as_data())
```

I get this error:

```
sequence item 0: expected str instance, ValidationError found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

```
form.errors = {
    'username': 
        ['This name is reserved and cannot be registered.'], 
    'password2': 
        ['This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.', 
        'This password is too common.']
}

error_string = ' '.join([' '.join(x for x in l) for l in list(form.errors.values())])

print(error_string)
>>> This name is reserved and cannot be registered. This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters. This password is too common.
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to join a list of error strings together, so use `form.errors['email']`.

```
error_string = ' '.join(form.errors['email'])
```

You don't want to use the [`as_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data) method, because it returns a list of `ValidationError` instances instead of strings.

Answer (score 2):

@bdoubleu answer didn't work for me, because it won't show the name of the field that has the error, only the error message,

```
error_string = ' '.join([' '.join(x for x in l) for l in list(form.errors.values())])

print(error_string)

>>> This field is required
```

(only shows the error, not the field) 
if you need both the field and the error message

```
target = list(form.errors) + list(form.errors.values())
error_string = ' '.join([l for l in target])

print(error_string)

>>> name This field is required
```

Comment: For better formatting, this can be achieved with: `''.join(f'{k}: {"".join(e for e in form.errors[k])}, ' for k in form.errors)`